# Adding File Indicator on PXGrid issue

Tags: acumatica

After enabling file indicator on my custom grid, I get prompted to save changes on the grid then get this error.

[image]

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

at PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog.a(Boolean& A_0) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog.GetAttachedFiles(Boolean& allowEdit) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog.a() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog.CreateChildControls() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXFilesDialog.DataBind() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.ap() 
at PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.a(PXCallbackCommand A_0) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.b(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0, XmlWriter A_1) 
at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.a(PXCallbackResultMethod A_0)
```

Comment: Does your DAC contain the NoteID field, decorated with PXNoteAttribute?

Comment: Is your DAC a database table or just virtual table (e.g. PXProjection)?

Comment: Its a database table, @RuslanDev No but thank you, do I add NoteID to the SQL table as a uniqueidentifier and declare it as a PXDBGuid() on my DAC?

Comment: @nickivey, yes, you need to add NoteID to the SQL table as a uniqueidentifier and declare it as PXNote() on your DAC